# Truncate paragraph except image to show/hide rest with View more link

Tags: jquery, truncate, expand

Hi as a newbie inJavascript/Jquery i need some help.
I have a class including text and image.
I want in case the text is more 70 characters the rest of it to be hidden except the image .Moreover i want at the end of the truncated text to see a link View more which on click will expand the full text.When text is expanded the link should become less doing the opposite .Im trying with slideToggle because to seems smoother..

This is what i tried but i di not manage either to keep images or to make view more link functional.
Your assistance appreciated :

```
var minimized_elements = $('.child_body').contents(':not(img)');

    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
        var t = $(this).text();        
        if(t.length < 70) return;

       $(this).html(t.slice(0,70)+'<span>...</span><a href="#" class="more">View More</a>');      

      $("a.more").click(function(){
        $("minimized_elements").slideToggle();
      });
   });
```

Comment: can you please create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f233xscj/2/ is this what you mean? edit: add character length check, and add more link

Comment: @wlin ,thanks a lot for your quick response!this very close to what i want but i would like  the default behavior to  be collapsed text if  #>70 and the effect to be smoother like slidetoggle !